# spring batch SQL queries without prepared statement

Tags: java, spring-batch

I read lines, generate SQL queries from the data and i need to write to the DB. My process is OK but i have trouble querying the DB with the writer. I think that i cannot use `PreparedStatement` as i have nothing else but the generated query and those query changes, so it will generate an error i think ( invalid batch command ). How can i simply put my SQL here ? Can i pass an attribute in the sql method like this : `.sql(query)` ? Btw i switched to `StringDTO` when i simply need a `String`. I had no other way to map the query to the `String` class, what would be the most appropriate ? It seems quite bad to create an object just to create a `String` inside

Here is my code :

```java
// tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
     @Bean
        public FlatFileItemReader<StringDTO> reader() {
            return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<StringDTO>()
                .name("StringDTOItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("file.edi"))
                .delimited()
                .delimiter("\\n")
                .names("query")
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<StringDTO>() {{
                    setTargetType(StringDTO.class);
                }})
                .build();
        }

    @Bean
    public StringDTOItemProcessor processor() {
        return new StringDTOItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ListUnpackingItemWriter<StringDTO> listItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
        ListUnpackingItemWriter<StringDTO> writer = new ListUnpackingItemWriter<>();
        writer.setDelegate(writer(dataSource));
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemPreparedStatementSetter<StringDTO> itemPreparedStatementSetter() {
        return new StatementSetterTest();
    }

    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<StringDTO> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<StringDTO>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql(":query")
                .itemPreparedStatementSetter(itemPreparedStatementSetter())
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .build();
    }
    // end::readerwriterprocessor[]

    // tag::jobstep[]
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(ItemWriter<List<StringDTO>> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<StringDTO, List<StringDTO>> chunk(300)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }
    // end::jobstep[]
```

---

Suggested solution :

```java
public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<String>{
    protected DataSource dataSource;

    public CustomWriter(DataSource dataSource){
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void write(final List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
        Statement statement = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
        Iterator<String> it = (Iterator<String>) items.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String s = it.next();
            if(s.startsWith("INSERT INTO SQD_SQI2_TKO (change_date,TKO,K991_0992,F2801,F2801,F2802,F1803) VALUES (sysdate,2467"))
                System.out.println(s);
            statement.addBatch(s);
        }

        statement.executeBatch();
    }
}public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<String>{
    protected DataSource dataSource;

    public CustomWriter(DataSource dataSource){
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void write(final List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
        Statement statement = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
        Iterator<String> it = (Iterator<String>) items.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String s = it.next();
            if(s.startsWith("INSERT INTO SQD_SQI2_TKO (change_date,TKO,K991_0992,F2801,F2801,F2802,F1803) VALUES (sysdate,2467"))
                System.out.println(s);
            statement.addBatch(s);
        }

        statement.executeBatch();
    }
}
```

---

Not related to initial question but here is the mapper i'm using as my output is just a `String` and doesn't require mapping to an actual object nor needs a to be mapped to the sql output

```java
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<String> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<String>()
            .name("StringItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("file.edi"))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter("\\n")
            .names("query")
            .fieldSetMapper(new FieldSetMapper<String>() {
                @Override
                public String mapFieldSet(FieldSet arg0) throws BindException {
                    return arg0.readString(0);
                }
            })
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: Does this mean your writer receives a list of queries to execute for all items of the current chunk?

Comment: Yes, exactly my processor does return a list of queries - queries concern multiple tables which is why i cannot use PreparedStatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my processor does return a list of queries - queries concern multiple tables

In this case, you need to use a custom item writer because the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` accepts a single query.

Comment: OK so it was my way to go for this morning, thanks. Another quick question, If you look at my reader, I did create a class named `StringDTO` with a String query attribute inside to map the data. Is there another way to go ? Should i completely remove the mapper as my process does return me the output i want and i dont need to map it to an object ?

Comment: So after completely removing the mapper, i get an error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No FieldSetMapper implementation was provided.` Is the mapper mandatory ? If so i just need to create a custom one doing nothing right ?

Comment: This is different problem, please ask a different question for that and I will try to help.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for your time, i added my solution on my initial post + i added my solution to the mapper issue i had